# Fullpage.js - Not working properly on "Laptop with Touch"

Tags: touch, fullpage.js

I have really strange problem.

All of sudden (obviously by itself) my website which uses Fullpage.js not working properly on laptop/desktops with touch. Unfortunately, the client has one :/..

You can try it yourself in inspect mode under "Laptop with Touch" and try to swipe with mouse over the screen.

Section sometimes decide to move to half of another, wait for few second and then jump to actual section.

Take a look -> https://vimeo.com/438350450

Do you know what can be the issue and how to fix it?

**Website** -> https://life-5.webflow.io/

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the styles for fullpage.js 2.9.7 but you are using the last JS version of fullPage.js which is 3.0.9.

Updatee the CSS to the latest:
https://unpkg.com/fullpage.js@3.0.9/dist/fullpage.min.css

Comment: Hey Sorry, for late answer.. But updating CSS hasnt fixed the issue :/ any more ideas?

Comment: All [the example pages](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#examples) seem to work properly. So not quite sure what can be the problem in your case. An isolated reproduction might help :)